# reset auto-increment each year with new prefix

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

I have an auto incremented field in my table. It should reset every new year 01/01 and then the prefix part should increment. 
For example in 2016 my auto incremented field was `A1,A2,A3..... etc` but on 12:00 AM 2017 it should reset to `B1` and go from there `(B1,B2,B3... etc), until Z when prefix should stop incrementing.

I created two tables... one for integer and one for varchar

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE t2
(
  id VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

and am creating a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg1
BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('A', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but am not sure how to involve date.

My db is mysql

Comment: This question is practically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536573/some-sort-of-different-auto-increment-indexes-per-a-primary-key-values/7714263#7714263 but the questions are slightly different, so I'm not voting to close. But you should go read my answer to that question, to explain some of the difficulty with what you're doing.

Comment: Why don't you just use an auto-incrementing INT column and a date column?

Comment: I don't want date as prefix. Prefix is a character