# Auto increment MySQL decimal number problems

Tags: mysql, numbers, decimal, fieldtype

I am building an application that will have one table of clients that has an autoincrement id INT field. Then I have an HTML "case" form where the user will have to chose a client from the dropdown, then add some info about "case" that will go into another table.

That means that the client will have an id of 1,2,3 and so on. And I would like that the case adds one decimal number on id number of the client chosen from dropdown. So for Client number two + 1: 2.1, 2.2 and so on. Client number 3, 3.1, 3.2 etc.

What is the best way to add that case filed to SQL? I see if I chose Decimal for a case id field I'm getting number 3.4 as 3.400 because I have chosen decimal 4,3 (MySQL) for testing. I Need to have such decimals because the number of cases can go to hundreds, I can not trim that. I'm struggling with the type of MySQL fields and how to approach this problem.
I'd appreciate some guidance.

The only thing I can think of is to pass the value of a client and then do id + "." + 1, and store it as decimal 1,1 (MySQL), will that auto autoincrement to 1.2 and so on?

Comment: i dont see the point of complicating life like that but yeah thats something you would do server side. get the count and concatenate the 2

Comment: I need to have that case field unique and based on the id of the client. And automatic, I can not let people enter either of those two pieces of information alone. If you have some other way that is simpler please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL auto-increment mechanism only increments by whole integers. Sorry, that's the way it is implemented.

The best way to design your `Case` table in MySQL is this:

```
CREATE TABLE Cases (
  case_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id INT NOT NULL,
  ...other attributes of the case...
  FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES Client (client_id)
);
```

It will have one auto-increment counter for the table, and all clients will need to share this number. This means the case numbers won't always be consecutive for a given client, and they won't start at 1 for each client. Sorry, that's the way auto-increment works in MySQL.

The question has been [asked many times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7536573/20860) with some variation of, "how can I make an auto-increment that renumbers for each group?" You could read the `MAX(case_id)` for the given client for which you need to insert a case, and then using the max case_id + 1 in your INSERT. In other words, forget about using the auto-increment feature, and calculate the id yourself.

You have to lock the table while doing this to avoid race conditions; two concurrent users could be inserting at the same time, and read the same value for MAX(case_id) and try to insert the same value.

Your plan of using decimal numbers will lead to problems.

- What if one day you have a client with more than 999 cases? You'd have to reformat all your case id's, not only for the client with 1000 cases, but for *all* clients. Any references to the case id's that you had sent out in paper statements and reports would become invalid.
- How would you do an SQL query to search for all cases for a given client? If you had client_id in its own column, it would be a query like `SELECT ... FROM Case WHERE client_id = 3` but if you have to do a query like `... WHERE case_id BETWEEN 3.000 AND 3.999` it's less clear and harder to optimize. It's also harder to explain to a new programmer you hire for the project. If you end up extending the id format to 4 digits past the decimal, you'd have to rewrite all these SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for answering and explaining, I am not a native English spiker and had trouble with explaining myself and searching for answers here, also didn't know about foreign keys. This is very well written and this is obviously a way to go if they want this to be an automatic process. Otherwise, they will have to do it manually. This way I will later just print client_id + . + case_id, that will be there reference number. Thank you for your time. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it. This is the best piece of advise I can give to you.

You are trying to use what was called "**Inteligent Codes**" back in the 80s.

They went out of fashion for a good reason. Very expensive to develop, non-mantainable, limited ranges, you-name-it. Stay away from them and use normal foreign keys instead. They give you all the flexibility you'll need when the application grows.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out foreign keys, I didn't know about them. I have chosen another answer just because it was much more explained. Thank you for your time.