# How can I create a self-incrementing ID per day in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a table

```
bills
( id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, idDay INT NULL
);
```

I want the 1st record of the idDay field of each day to be 1 and from there continue the incremental, example:

```
|    id    |    createdAt   | idDay |
|----------|----------------|-------|
| 1        | 2021-01-10     |   1   |
| 2        | 2021-01-10     |   2   |
| 3        | 2021-01-11     |   1   |
| 4        | 2021-01-11     |   2   |
| 5        | 2021-01-11     |   3   |
| 6        | 2021-01-12     |   1   |
| 7        | 2021-01-13     |   1   |
| 8        | 2021-01-13     |   2   |
```

It's necessary the idDay field? or can i do this in the select?.
I think I can do this with a procedure but how?.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not hash the date?

Comment: You ask the question "It's necessary the idDay field?" - you are the one who can answer that question (and I think it's the first question that needs to be answered).  What do you believe you are achieving by having that field?  What are you hoping / expecting to use that field for (that you can't achieve with just the "id" and "createdAt" fields)?

Comment: @Craig , you are right, i mean if i can do this only with the select its not necessary for me.

Comment: In that case, @sticky bit's answer will get you there, by generating the auto-increment per date in a SELECT statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536573/some-sort-of-different-auto-increment-indexes-per-a-primary-key-values/7714263#7714263

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function available since MySQL 8.

```
SELECT id,
       createdat,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date(createdat)
                          ORDER BY id) idday
       FROM bill;
```

(Or `ORDER BY createdat`, if that defines the order, not the `id`.)

But since window functions are calculated after a `WHERE` clause is applied, the number might be different for a record if previous records for a day are filtered. It's not clear from your question if this is a problem or not. If it is a problem, you can use the query in a derived table or create a view with it and work on that.

Yet another option is a correlated subquery counting the "older" records.

```
SELECT b1.id,
       b1.createdat,
       (SELECT count(*) + 1
               FROM bill b2
               WHERE b2.createdat >= date(b1.cratedat)
                     AND b2.createdat < date_add(date(b1.createdat), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
                     AND b2.id < b1.id) idday
       FROM bill b1;
```

(If `createdat` defines the order, change `b2.createdat < date_add(date(b1.createdat), INTERVAL 1 DAY))` to `b2.createdat <= b1.createdat`.)
That would also work in lower MySQL versions and you can add a `WHERE` clause (to the outer query) without changing the numbers.

Comment: that only works if, for each record you want to get, you also want all the previous records for that day.  otherwise, you will need a subquery, at which point you might as well use a self join

Comment: @ysth: Fair point. I edited the answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate the number in a select (requires an index on createdAt to work well):

```
select b.id, b.createdAt, count(b2.id)+1 as idDay
from bill b
left join bill b2 on b2.createdAt=b.createdAt and b2.id < b.id
where ...
group by b.id
```